# SSAS fact and Dimension relations

Tags: ssas

I have the data that is going to rollover everymonth if the data condition is active. Below is the example

Source data:

```
DID YearMonth  Createddatekey count
a 201307 20130701 1
b 201307 20130701 1
a 201308 20130701 1
b 201308 20130701 1
c 201308 20130801 1
```

Required output:

Expected

```
output 
Yearmonth Count
201307 2
201308 1
```

I can get the results in the SQL by just adding the condition as below.

```
  select Createdatekey,count(*) from table with (nolock)
  Where Createdatekey>=20130701 and YearMonth=201307   
  Group by Createdatekey
```

But when I created the Hierarchy in the Datedimension by joining the Createdatekey it's giving the combine relsult irrespective of months.

How can I achieve that SQL condition what I written in SSAS cube model?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue.  Can you elaborate on what this means "But when I created the Hierarchy in the Datedimension by joining the Creaatedatekey its giving the combine relsult irrespective of months." and restate your goal?

Comment: DimDate table is the Dimension and I have tied up with the Dimdate table column Datekey with Fact table coulmun Createdatekey. Then I have created Datekey->MonthID ->Quarter->Year. When I see the results for the results for 201307 Yearmonth Count
201307 A 2 201307 B 2. I shouldn't want to happen this. I want to know that particular month how many have created.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to create a measure in a SSAS cube that provides a distinct count of DID from your fact table based upon the YearMonth of the CreateDateKey.

I'm not sure if you are doing multidimensional or tabular, so here are suggestions for both.  It sounds like you already have your table properly related to your date dimension. For multidimensional, you can create a measure and make sure you select DID as the source column and Distinct count as the usage.[image: SSAS Measure]

In tabular, create a calculated measure that is

```
distinctcount([DID])
```

Comment: This will not work in my case. Since this is Roll over and I need to address that in Each month how many got created newly.

Comment: Are you saying that you want some kind of cumulative running total rather than distinct count by month?